# Finding optimal rotation matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, geometry, vector, rotation

I have vectors `E1 = {22.607, 3.495, -30.795};` and `R1 = { 4.74061, 21.7549, 30.6501};`. This vectors are conneted by a 3D rotation such that `R1 = Rot. E1` `Rot` is the roation matrix (there can be some error due to measurment). 
How to find the optimal rotation matrix so that it can be applied to another set of vectors which goes through same transformation.
PS. the other set is let's say `E2 = {-13.236, 25.903, 13.937};` and `R2 = {-17.5342, -26.6773, -0.10567};`. Now we know only `R2`

Comment: @MichaelE2 you mean `FindGeometricTransform`.

Comment: Note that with just E1 and R1, the answer is ambiguous. Given a rotation that takes E1 to R1, you may follow it with any rotation about the R1 axis and still have a correct result. Which result will take E2 to R2 is unpredictable without an additional constraint.

Comment: @John Exactly this is the point I was wondering. Could you please something more about the constrains?

Comment: @rhermans So much for going from memory.  Thx.

Comment: @Xavier Please [edit] your question to explain what do you mean by *"Optimal"*  and **explain in detail** what you really need. Please don't make us guess.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your problem is. To determine spacecraft orientation from star tracker data, you need at least two stars. For the HETE-2 space mission, we had great success with the algorithm at http://space.mit.edu/home/jpd/LinTrigFunc.html, translated to C. `FindGeometricTransform` presumably has something similar inside it.

Comment: Just one remark: Vectors r1 and e1  have different length, so the rotation is only an approximation

Answer (score 7):

### [`RotationMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html)

```
rotm = With[
   {
    e1 = {22.607, 3.495, -30.795},
    r1 = {4.74061, 21.7549, 30.6501}
    }
   , (Norm[r1]/Norm[e1]) RotationMatrix[{e1, r1}]
   ];

MatrixForm[rotm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
rotm.{22.607, 3.495, -30.795}
(* {4.74061, 21.7549, 30.6501} *)
```

### [`TransformationFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction.html)

```
transfunc = With[
  {
   e1 = {22.607, 3.495, -30.795},
   r1 = {4.74061, 21.7549, 30.6501}
   },
  Last@FindGeometricTransform[{r1}, {e1}]
  ]

transfunc[{22.607, 3.495, -30.795}]
(* {4.74061, 21.7549, 30.6501} *)
```